# How to calculate the sum of prime numbers that comes till 20? i.e total should be 77 but below solution gives 277

Tags: java

I want sum of prime numbers upto 20. That is 77 but my solution is giving me 277. Please help.

```
import java.util.*;


public class PrimeSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(primesum(20));
    }

    static long primesum(int maxNum) 
    {
        int sum = 0, num;
        num=maxNum;
        if(maxNum<=0)
        return sum;
        else
      {
        boolean prime[]=new boolean[num + 1];
        Arrays.fill(prime, true);
        for (int p = 2; p * p <= num; p++) 
        {
            if (prime[p] == true) 
            {

                for (int i = p * 2; i <= num; i += p)
                prime[i] = false;
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++)
            if (prime[i])
                sum += i;

        }
        return sum;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well ... time to debug.

Comment: Your indentation is very irregular. If you make sure that all sections are indented properly, it will be easier to debug

Comment: corrected it. I am new to coding so please bear with my coding style.

Answer (score 1):

Because of your indentation and lack of clean code structure, you've created an error. If you noticed, you're summing all of the prime values in every single for loop iteration in the outer for loop. That's your problem. This part here:

```java
if (prime[i])
   sum += i;
```

is happening during every loop of the outer for loop.

That being said, you're trying to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm. Here's a working version of it:

```java
  public static int sieveOfEratosthenes(int n) {
    boolean isPrime[] = new boolean[n+1];
    Arrays.fill(isPrime, true);

    for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++) {
      if (isPrime[p]) {
        for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
          isPrime[i] = false;
      }
    }

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i < isPrime.length; i++) {
      if(isPrime[i]) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

I hope that helps :)

EDIT: I cleaned up your code a bit so you can see where the error is a little more clearly:

```java
  static long primeSum(int maxNum) {
    int sum = 0, num;
    num = maxNum;
    if (maxNum <= 0) {
      return sum;
    } else {
      boolean prime[] = new boolean[num + 1];
      Arrays.fill(prime, true);
      for (int p = 2; p * p <= num; p++) {
        if (prime[p] == true) {
          for (int i = p * 2; i <= num; i += p) {
            prime[i] = false;
          }
        }
        // This is where your mistake is. See how it's in the outer for loop?
        for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
          if (prime[i]) {
            sum += i;
          }
        }
      }
      return sum;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is again giving me 255.

Comment: I didn't fix yours. I showed you where yours went wrong. The first one, titled "sieveOfEratosthenes" is a correctly working implementation.

Comment: ok got it. Thanks it works.

Comment: Feel free to "accept" the answer so it's easier for other users to see as a solution to their potential problem down the road! :)

Comment: Some words of explanation for my downvote on this post: As I understand it, the goal of SO is to provide general answers to general questions. That is, we try to use our words to help the OP understand the problem they're trying to solve. Here, you've simply provided working code, which does nothing to help the OP do better next time, and provides no useful help for anyone in the future. Therefore, I consider this not a helpful answer (even if the OP is delighted to have been spared the work of learning something)

Comment: Well thank you for the explanation, however I do feel like I addressed it in multiple ways. I showed where his code was making a mistake, a cleaned up version of his code so it was easier to see where the mistake was made - along with a comment to point it out even more clearly, and then a working implementation to compare it to. I appreciate the feedback, however! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the numbers, and sum up a store if the number is prime.

**Noting that**

**0 & 1 are not prime numbers.**

**To check if a number (n) is a prime:** it should not get a reminder of 0 when it's divided by any number between 2 & n-1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // collecting the sum of prime numbers into sum
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i))
        sum += i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);

}
// Returning true if the number is a prime, and false otherwise
static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    // 0 & 1 are not prime numbers
    if (n <= 1)
        return false;

    // Check from 2 to n-1
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

**Output:** 
77